# How can i reach twitter profile photo in fabric?(Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, twitter, authentication, user-profile, twitter-fabric

**In unity,I use crashanalitycs and twitter kits  I can login users.I can id,username,authtoken but i can't reach profile photos.Can i reach profile photos in fabric?**

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Currently, there isn't a way to get the profile photo of a Twitter user from Fabric.